# onEnter prop triggers on all components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking for help with my react router onEnter prop. Seems like that onEnter prop is triggered on every component in my app, event though I am not specifying that.
Pretty sure it is something related with my router setup.

My code:

```
<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route
      path="/1"
      components={{ main: Hierarchy, sidebar: NavBar }}
      onEnter={AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
    />
    <Route
      path="/2"
      components={{ main: Entities, sidebar: NavBar }}
      onEnter={AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
    />
    <Route
      path="/2/:id"
      component={Analysis}
      onEnter={AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
    />
    <Route path="/1/:id" component={Entity} onEnter={AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" component={AuthForm} />
  <Route path="/new-password" component={ChangePasswordForm} />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Actually **@bennygenel** spotted the issue you're having with the authentication happening on every route. But there is another issue with your routing which I'll cover below:

---

You have an issue with the order in which you have defined your routes.

For example, if you visit `/login` the route will satisfy `<Route path="/" />` and enter that. Similarly, visiting `/1/ABC` will satisfy `<Route path="/1" />` and enter that. Generally, you should define the stricter/more specific routes first, then the more general ones.

You should define them like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/login" component={AuthForm} />
  <Route path="/new-password" component={ChangePasswordForm} />
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="/1/:id" component={Entity} onEnter={() => AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)} />
    <Route
      path="/1"
      components={{ main: Hierarchy, sidebar: NavBar }}
      onEnter={() => AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
    />
    <Route
      path="/2/:id"
      component={Analysis}
      onEnter={() => AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
    />
    <Route
      path="/2"
      components={{ main: Entities, sidebar: NavBar }}
      onEnter={() => AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
    />
  </Route>      
</Router>
```

You should check out [the Precedence section](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#precedence) from the official docs:

> Finally, the routing algorithm attempts to match routes in the order
>   they are defined, top to bottom. So, when you have two sibling routes
>   you should be sure the first doesn't match all possible `path`s that can
>   be matched by the later sibling. For example, **don't** do this:
>
> ```
> <Route path="/comments" ... />
> <Redirect from="/comments" ... />
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is that you are executing the function rather then sending it as a prop.

This

```
 onEnter={AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
```

should be

```
 onEnter={() => AWSApi.tokenIsValid(authHeader)}
```